# Regex should not match numbers inside parenthesis

Tags: regex, perl

I have a passage of verses and they are numbered. I want each numbered verse in separate line so I add a new line before them but I have some parenthesis that also have numbers. They too are replaced by new lines. I don't want to match the numbers inside parenthesis. I used

```
$_=~s/(\d+)/\n$1 /gs;
```

with this input:

```
1Hello2Hai (in 2:3) 3hi 4 bye
```

but it replaces the numbers inside paranthesis also.

Required output :

```
1 Hello
2 Hai (in 2:3)
3 hi
4 bye
```

Actual output:

```
1 Hello
2 Hai (in
2:
3)
3 hi
4 bye
```

How do I construct the regex so that it doesn't match inside parenthesis. I use `perl` for the `regex`.

Comment: Can be any case with nested parentheses?

Comment: Ya there can be anything inside paranthesis but mostly numbers and symbols(:,-) @Birei

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my $stro = <<'END';
1Hello2Hai (in 2:3) 3hi 4 bye
END

$stro =~s/(\((?>[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s*(\d+)\s*/\n$2 /g;

print $stro;
```

pattern details:

The idea is to skip content in parenthesis. To do that I try to match parenthesis first with this recursive subpattern: `(\((?>[^()]++|(?1))*\))` and I make the subpattern fail and force the regex engine to not retry the substring with an other alternative with `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)` backtracking control verbs.

`(*SKIP)` forces to not retry the content matched on his left if the subpattern will fail later.

`(*FAIL)` forces the subpattern to fail.

**An other way:**

As you can read in [the perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), backtracking control verbs are an experimental regex feature and should be mentioned in a production code. *(However, this feature exists for several years.)*

Here is a simple way without these features: You match all that precedes a number and you remove it from the match result with the `\K` feature:

```
s/(?:(\((?>[^()]++|(?1))*\))|[^\d(]+)*\K\s*(\d+)\s*/\n$2 /g
```

Comment: Did u check the output for the test case I provided? I get an error here @Casimir . Sorry I am new to perl what does *SKIP and *FAIL mean?

Comment: Sorry I had both perl script and a text file in the same name and with perl <filename> it had run the text file. I will mark it as answer. Thanks a lot. Please provide me a link to learn about skip and fail @Casimir

Comment: @xtreak: you can find informations about this feature by following the link in my answer or by reading this fabulous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992984/verbs-that-act-after-backtracking-and-failure :)

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern
`(\D+)(\d+)(?=((?!\)).)*\(|[^()]*$)` with /g option
and replace with `$1\n$2` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tV8sM8)

or to adjust the indentation use this pattern
`(\d+)\s*(?=((?!\)).)*\(|[^()]*$)`  with /g option
and replace with `\n$1` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yO4kO6)
except you have to get rid of the first blank line