# Exclude match results (pcre regex)

Tags: regex, match, pcre

So I've this regex (from https://github.com/savetheinternet/Tinyboard/blob/master/inc/functions.php#L1620)

```
((?:https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|irc:\/\/)[^\s<>()"]+?(?:\([^\s<>()"]*?\)[^\s<>()"]*?)*)((?:\s|<|>|"|\.|\]|!|\?|,|&#44;|&quot;)*(?:[\s<>()"]|$))
```

it works for matching links like: `http://stackoverflow.com/` etc..

question is, how I can exclude these kind of markup matches (mainly the url ja img parts):

```
[url]http://stackoverflow.com/[/url]
[url=http://stackoverflow.com/]http://stackoverflow.com/[/url]
[img]http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png[/img]
[img=http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png]
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your input?

Answer (score 3):

To exclude this you can add at the begining of your expression this subpattern:

```
(?:\[(url|img)](?>[^[]++|[(?!\/\g{-1}))*+\[\/\g{-1}]|\[(?:url|img)=[^]]*+])(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|your pattern here
```

The goal of this is to try to match the parts you don't want before and forces the regex engine to fail with the backtracking control verb `(*FAIL)`. The `(*SKIP)` verb forces the regex engine to not retry the substring matched before when the subpattern fails after.

You can find more informations about these features [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992984/verbs-that-act-after-backtracking-and-failure).

Notice: assuming that you are using PHP for this pattern, you can improve a little bit this very long pattern by replacing the default delimiter `/` by `~` to avoid to escape all `/` in the pattern and by using the verbose mode (x modifier) with a Nowdoc syntax. Like this you can comment it, make it more readable and easily improve the pattern

Example:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOF'
~
### skipping url and img bbcodes ###
(?:
    \[(url|img)]              # opening bbcode tag
    (?>[^[]++|[(?!/\g{-1}))*+ # possible content between tags
    \[/\g{-1}]                # closing bbcode tag
  |
    \[(?:url|img)= [^]]*+ ]   # self closing bbcode tags
)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)            # forces to fail and skip

| # OR

### a link ###
(
    (?:https?|ftp|irc)://      # protocol
    [^\s<>()"]+?
    (?:
        \( [^\s<>()"]*? \)     # part between parenthesis
        [^\s<>()"]*?
    )*
)
(
    (?:[]\s<>".!?,]|&#44;|&quot;)*
    (?:[\s<>()"]|$)
)
~x
EOF;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it with *negative look-behind assertion*.

```
(?<!pattern)
```

In your case, you can check if there is no `]` or `=` character just before the matching link.
Below regex will make sure that exactly this doesn't happen:

```
(?<!(?:\=|\]))((?:https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|irc:\/\/)[^\s<>()"]+?(?:\([^\s<>()"]*?\)[^\s<>()"]*?)*)((?:\s|<|>|"|\.|\]|!|\?|,|&#44;|&quot;)*(?:[\s<>()"]|$))
```

Note that the only part added is `(?<!(?:\=|\]))` right in the beginning and that it will not match a link in something like `<a href=http://example.com>` but your question does not specify this... so impove the question if that's expected behaviour or work it out yourself using negative look behind.