# escape string but not in "'s

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a string like:

```
'word1 \nword2 "word3 \nword4" word5 \nword6'
```

and I want to became like

```
'word1 
word2 "word3 \nword4" word5 
word6'
```

I couldn't write any success regexp pattern. Is this possible ?

Comment: Where do you want to render this string?

Comment: I'm gonna write it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_split for this task:

```
$result = preg_split('/"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s*\\n\s*/', $txt);
```

You obtain the parts you want in an array, you can make all what you want after. (write a file line by line, implode with a CRLF...)

More informations about `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)`: [Verbs that act after backtracking and failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992984/verbs-that-act-after-backtracking-and-failure)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by regex, my way is kinda complex, maybe someone has better solution

```
$subject = <<<'SUBJECT'
'word1 \nword2 "special \n \"character" word5 \nword6'
SUBJECT;

$callback = function ($matches1) {
    if (preg_match_all(
<<<PATTERN
/"(?:\"|[^"])+?"/
PATTERN
        , $matches1[0], $matches2, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        $pointer = 0;
        $arr = [];
        foreach ($matches2[0] as $match2) {
            $arr[] = substr($matches1[0], $pointer, $match2[1]);
            $arr[] = $match2[0];
            $pointer = $match2[1] + strlen($match2[0]);
        }
        $arr[] = substr($matches1[0], $pointer, strlen($matches1[0]));
        foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) {
            if (!($key % 2)) { 
                $value = preg_replace('/\Q\n\E/', "\n", $value); 
            }
        }
        return implode('', $arr);
    }
    return $matches1[0];
};
$result = preg_replace_callback(
<<<PATTERN
/'(?:\'|[^'])+?'/
PATTERN
, $callback, $subject);
file_put_contents('doc.txt', $result);
```