# Parse sentence with php preg_replace_callback and ignore data inside parenthesis

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have this string,

> A large hoofed mammal (Equus caballus) having a short-haired coat, a
>   long mane, and a long tail, domesticated since ancient times and used
>   for riding and for drawing or carrying loads.

which needs to be converted into this:

**A [large](http://words.com/large) [hoofed](http://words.com/hoofed) [mammal](http://words.com/mammal) (Equus caballus) [having](http://words.com/having) a [short](http://words.com/short)-[haired](http://words.com/haired) coat, a long mane, and a long tail, [domesticated](http://words.com/domesticated) [since](http://words.com/since) [ancient](http://words.com/ancient) [times](http://words.com/times) and used for [riding](http://words.com/riding) and for [drawing](http://words.com/drawing) or [carrying](http://words.com/carrying) [loads](http://words.com/loads).**

These are the requirements:

1. words with a length of 5+ have to be encapsulated inside an a href tag. *(this is already solved)*
2. words inside parenthesis have to be ignored. **This is the missing requirement in the regex**

Currently, the code below is converting the original string into this (data inside parenthesis is not being ignored as it should be):

**A [large](http://words.com/large) [hoofed](http://words.com/hoofed) [mammal](http://words.com/mammal) ([Equus](http://words.com/equus) [caballus](http://words.com/caballus)) [having](http://words.com/having) a [short](http://words.com/short)-[haired](http://words.com/haired) coat, a long mane, and a long tail, [domesticated](http://words.com/domesticated) [since](http://words.com/since) [ancient](http://words.com/ancient) [times](http://words.com/times) and used for [riding](http://words.com/riding) and for [drawing](http://words.com/drawing) or [carrying](http://words.com/carrying) [loads](http://words.com/loads).**

This is my current code:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/\b[\p{L}\p{M}]{5,}\b/u', create_function(
    '$matches',
    'return "<a href=\"http://words.com/".strtolower($matches[0])."\">$matches[0]</a>";'
), $data);
```

How can I implement the 2nd requirement in the same regex?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a capture group:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('~(\([^)]+\))|[\pL\pM]{5,}~u', function ($m) {
    if (empty($m[1]))
        return '<a href="http://words.com/' . strtolower($m[0]) . '">' . $m[0] . '</a>';
    return $m[1];
}, $data);
```

or you can use [backtracking control verbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992984/verbs-that-act-after-backtracking-and-failure/20008790#20008790) `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('~\([^)]+\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[\pL\pM]{5,}~u', function ($m) {
    return '<a href="http://words.com/' . strtolower($m[0]) . '">' . $m[0] . '</a>';
}, $data);
```

Comment: I used the capture group version. Worked great, thanks!