# Check if a line does not start with a specific string with grep

Tags: shell, grep

I have a file app.log

```
Oct 06 03:51:43 test test
Nov 06 15:04:53 text text text 
more text more text
Nov 06 15:06:43 text text text
Nov 06 15:07:33
more text more text
Nov 06 15:14:23  test test
more text more text
some more text 
Nothing but text
some extra text
Nov 06 15:34:31 test test test
```

How do I grep all the lines that does not begin with Nov 06 ?

I have tried

```
grep -En "^[^Nov 06]" app.log
```

I am not able to get lines which have 06 in them.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Simply use the below grep command,

```
grep -v '^Nov 06' file
```

From `grep --help`,

```
-v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
```

Another hack through regex,

```
grep -P '^(?!Nov 06)' file
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `(?!Nov 06)` This negative lookahead asserts that there isn't a string `Nov 06` following the line start. If yes, then match the boundary exists before first character in each line.

Another regex based solution through PCRE verb [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008790/3622940)

```
grep -P '^Nov 06(*SKIP)(*F)|^' file
```

Comment: +1 that was really faaaaast!!

Comment: I just got the answer too :/
But Thank you :)