# grep- using regex to print all lines that do not contain a pattern (without -v)

Tags: regex, grep

How can I use regex, with grep, to print all lines that do not contain a pattern. I cannot use `-v` because I want to implement the regex within a much more complicated one, for which `-v` would be impractical.

But whenever I try to print lines that do not contain a pattern, I do not get the expected output.

For example, if I have this file:

```
blah blah blah
hello world
hello people
something
```

And I want to print all lines that do not contain `hello`, the output should be:

```
blah blah blah
something
```

I tried something like this, but it won't work:

```
egrep '[^hello]' file
```

All answers on SO use `-v`, I can't find one using regex

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804586/grep-to-check-if-a-line-starts-with-a-specific-string . ie, `grep -P '^.*hello(*SKIP)(*F)|^' file`

Comment: You can also pipe the output of grep to another grep. There is no need to do everything in one grep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use "whole" words inside of a character class. Your regular expression currently matches any character except: `h`, `e`, `l`, `o`.  You could use grep with the following option and implement [Negative Lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) ...

```
grep -P '^(?!.*hello).*$' file
```

- `-P` option interprets the pattern as a [Perl regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

#### [Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/sTRTHD)

Comment: you don't need to add `-o` parameter when you're trying to print the whole line. Just `grep -P '^(?!.*hello)' file` would be fine. This matches the start of a line only it won't contain the word `hello`. `-p` alone helps you to print those matched lines.

Answer (score 1):

I see you asking for regex, and can not use `-v`.  What about some other program like `awk,sed`?
If not, does your system not have `awk`, `sed` etc?

```
awk '!/hello/' file
```

```
sed '/hello/d' file
```

```
sed -n '/hello/!p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help you.

```
grep -E '^[^(hello)]*$' file
```