# RegEx: Match format around text;

Tags: php, regex

I have an instance in a project where I need to match some text within a description or title;

The requirements for matching are as follows;

### Should Match:

a) Any occurrences of "Volume" OR "Part" (Case Insensitive);

b) Any occurrence of "vol" or "pt" (CI) that does not have [[comma][space] before AND [period] after;

I have tried numerous different regex patterns (count down from the 4) on regex101 here: http://regex101.com/r/lO9vO9/4

In that link, theres a few lines that fail, that I would like to, ideally, match.

`. pt.` as it contains the pt with trailing period, but has the wrong character (period) before it when expecting a comma

`The Red Pill, Pt 2` As it contains the preceding comma and the PT, but misses the period after PT.

If someone can help me with this, I would appreciate it if a run down of how it works was available too - so I can figure out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(,\s(?:vol|pt)\.(*SKIP)(*F)|\b(?:volume|pt|vol|part)\b)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lO9vO9/6)

This part `,\s(?:vol|pt)\.` just matches your negative pattern and `(*SKIP)(*F)` just skips it from final match.

[**More info on `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992984/verbs-that-act-after-backtracking-and-failure)

Comment: "volume" should come before "vol" in the last part, otherwise "volume" won't be found. (*SKIP) and (*F) are new to me. Where can I get info on them?

Comment: Ok that regex is updated, **[see this Q&A for more info on these features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992984/verbs-that-act-after-backtracking-and-failure)**

Answer (score 1):

So, in other words you want to forbid, pt & vol not followed by a dot, and pt & vol not preceded by a comma and a space:

```
volume|part|(?<!, )(?:vol|pt)|(?:vol|pt)(?!\.)
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/jM5mL2/3)

Note: you can improve this pattern by adding a lookahead and word boundary at the begining *(in this way, the alternation is only tested for words that begin with p and v)*. You can check too that "vol" or "pt" is not the begining of another word by forcing that no letters follow.

```
(?=\b[pv])(?:volume|part|(?<!, )(?:vol|pt)|(?:vol|pt)(?!\.))(?![a-z])
```